# Probability of At Least One Success and At Least One Failure

Tags: probability, combinatorics

(a) Independent Bernoulli trials are performed, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of success, until
there has been at least one success. Find the PMF of the number of trials performed.

(b) Independent Bernoulli trials are performed, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of success, until
there has been at least one success and at least one failure. Find the PMF of the number
of trials performed.

The solution for part (a) is $P(N = n) = (\frac{1}{2})^{n - 1} \frac{1}{2}$ where $N$ is the number of Bernoulli trails.

The given solution for part (b) says to use the solution for part (a) by letting the first trial occur and letting that event be failure, then just finding $P(N = n - 1)$ to be the PMF.

However, I tried to find a general solution where $p$ is the probability of success and $1 - p = 1$ is the probability of failure, which gave:
$$
P(N = n) = p^{n - 1}q \binom{n}{1} + p^{2}q^2 \binom{n}{n -2} + \cdots + p^2 q^{n - 2} \binom{n}{n - 2} + pq^{n - 1} \binom{n}{1} = (\frac{1}{2})^n (2^n - 2)
$$
which does not match when I plug in the answer. Why doesn't this expression work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is the probability of success for one Bernoulli trial.

Suppose it takes $N\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ trials until there has been at least one success and at least one failure.  This can never happen for $N=1$. For $N\geq 2$, this can only be the case if the first $N-1$ trials were successes and the $N$th trial was a failure, or the first $N-1$ trials were failures and the $N$th trial was a success. Thus, $$P(N=n)=p^{n-1}(1-p)+(1-p)^{n-1}p, \quad n=2,3,4...$$

Answer (score 2):

There <strike>are two</strike> is one major mistake in your answer.

To calculate $P(N=n)$, you need to enumerate sequences which achieve both a success and a failure *for the first time* in $n$ attempts. You are ignoring the the "for the first time" condition, and just counting sequences of length $n$ with at least one success and failure.

In order for $n$ to be the first time that both a success and failure are attained, the first $n-1$ outcomes need to be the same as each other, either all successes or all failures. This means there are two valid sequences, either SS...SF or FF...FS, where $S$ is success and $F$ is failure. Both of these have a probability of $(1/2)^n$, so the total probability is $2\cdot (1/2)^n=(1/2)^{n-1}$. Necessarily, $n\ge 2$.

Comment: I assumed OP's simplification was in the special case $p=q=1/2$, in which case the binomial theorem was applied correctly (though not giving the correct answer to the question).

Comment: You are right, I was wrong.